# Obj-C Instance method returning a instanceType called from Swift - Function produces expected type 'UIImage!' error

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have this instance method in an existing Obj-C UIImage category:

```
- (UIImage *)applyDarkEffect;
```

I'm trying to call it from a Swift file like so:

```
 self.backgroundImageView.image = UIImage.applyDarkEffect(image)
```

But get this compiler error:

```
Function produces expected type 'UIImage!'; did you mean to call it with '()'?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the method you have defined in Objective C image category, it is instance method and you are trying to call it using UIImage class in swift.

You can basically use either one of the following two approaches,

Either,

```
self.backgroundImageView.image = self.someImage.applyDarkEffect() // notice the method does not take argument
```

Or if you want to use class level method, then first create a closure and call it as,

```
let applyEffectToImageClosure = UIImage.applyDarkEffect(self.someImage)
self.backgroundImageView.image = applyEffectToImageClosure()
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, those two don't match. Your Objective-C method doesn't take any parameters, but in your Swift code you are trying to pass a parameter called `image`

Your Objective-C method is an instance method, and your Swift code is trying to invoke a class method, which is another mismatch.

Your Swift code should look like this:

```
self.backgroundImageView.image = someImage.applyDarkEffect()
```

(Where `someImage` is an instance of UIImage that you want to send the `applyDarkEffect` message to.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is that the method is an instance method (the - at the beginning on the declaration) but you are attempting to call it as a [type method](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Methods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH15-ID241).

You will need to call it with a `UIImage`, assuming you want to apply a dark effect to the existing image:-

```
self.backgroundImageView.image = image.applyDarkEffect()
```

It may also be worth mentioning that you can call it as a type method but passing in the instance you want to work upon:-

```
self.backgroundImageView.image = UIImage.applyDarkEffect(image)()
```